# Looking for a limerick, tongue twister or haiku

Tags: tongue-twisters

Has anyone come across a limerick, tongue twister or hai ku relating to the following words?

pear, pair, pare

Or does anyone want to make an attempt, something along the lines of "woodchuck chuck" or "which witch"

Comment: This appears to be off-topic, asking for help with English misusage.

Comment: Where should it go?  I saw similar questions once before and when I looked for sites here I could not find anything better. I was not asking for misusage (sic.) if that bothers you, it is allowed (and kind of nice) if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: misusage: 

1
:  bad treatment :  abuse
2
:  wrong or improper use (as of words) [M-W] I thought about the word before I used it. // ELU is not a provider of resources, and I can't see how woodchucks chucking is highly relevant in a site aimed at serious English language enthusiasts.

Comment: I do apologise for trying to be humorous, even though it does appear from comments below that you do possess a sense thereof.  It was a bit presumptuous of you to assume that my question was not about ELU though.  I would have been most grateful if you had indicated a better place to pose my question and perhaps indicate where I can read up on the seriousness level of the ELU group. I have read a less serious stuff than my query here.

Comment: Writers SE has at least one question dealing with limericks. // The ELU introduction specifies that questions are welcome on:
Word choice and usage / 
Grammar / 
Etymology (history of words’ development) / 
Dialect differences / 
Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology) / 
Spelling and punctuation. Perhaps it's a bit presumptuous to invite people to submit limericks. // I believe I have a fine sense of humour. You failed to pick this up in my first comment.  I'm witty half the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is both a request for resources (a reference to a poem etc fulfilling certain conditions) and a request for novel pieces of poetry etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fine, I'll second your request, how does voting work here at ELU?

Comment: There is a Help Center explaining (1) how the site works; (2) the type of questions that are welcome ... Demands like 'Where should it go?' / '... how does voting work here at ELU?' are _not_  suitable here. Although I have suggested 'Writers SE' (which I know little about, but took the trouble to have a look at on your behalf).

Comment: Thanks, I had a look in the help, I have been advised.  I agree that my question is too open ended for the guidelines so you can close it.  If the voting you proposed shows in the number beside question I have seen changes already.  I already acknowledged your sense of humour even though it was not in any of your comments to me. Calling my request a demand is not good English use. Thank you for spotting Writers SE (I did not see your first mention of it as I missed the first of your double comment) I shall mode over to there.

Comment: Next time you want something like this, please come to [chat].

Comment: The pair of aux pairs in Paris repaired the pair of poorly pared pears and prepared and paired them nicely with a Dom-Pér d’avant-guerre. @KalleMP (not really hard to recite sober, but after a few it might get a bit twisted)

Comment: Said the peer who pares pears it appears, that while paring your pears on a pier, if preparing to pare, or just pairing a pear, at your pairs and your pears you must peer. Sorry, it kept me up last night, I needed to get it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There once was a Finnish au pair,

Who sliced two fruits on a dare,

Her host was a lord,

So she took a sharp sword,

Then that au pair pared a peer's pear pair.

Comment: Good effort, Mark.

Comment: @MarkBannister Thank you adding in the peer and au pair, that is definitely worthy of correct answer.  You get the up vote for slipping in the Finnish connection. I hope you don't get into trouble for getting best answer on a controversial question, your reputation points may vanish if it gets deleted.  I have copied it and will showcase it on my profile here and use it again elsewhere with attribution if you have no objection.

Comment: @KalleMP: I have no objection at all - I am glad you liked it!

Answer (score 2):

There once was a Poster did dare,

Ask for rhyming with Pear, Pair and Pare.

But Edwin chastised,

The OP was denied,

And the rhyming did not appear there.

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote. And downvote.

Comment: I was hoping for something relating to the words but thank you for your answer relating to the comments.